# how to set default culture info for entire c# application

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, globalization, cultureinfo, invariantculture

I want to set default culture info for that class or for entire application.

For example in Turkey 3,2 = in english 3.2

so application uses my local but i want it to use as default

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
```

How can i set it to that as default for that specific class or for entire application

Comment: I have to add that the non-invariant versions of <TNumber>.ToString() are much slower, and that "Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture"  does not make a difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way of setting culture for a whole application? All current threads and new threads?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468791/is-there-a-way-of-setting-culture-for-a-whole-application-all-current-threads-a)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Not for entire application or particular class.

CurrentUICulture and CurrentCulture are settable per thread as discussed here [Is there a way of setting culture for a whole application? All current threads and new threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468791/setting-currentculture-and-currentuiculture-of-an-application). You can't change `InvariantCulture` at all.

Sample code to change cultures for current thread:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(theCultureString);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
```

For class you can set/restore culture inside critical methods, but it would be significantly safe to use appropriate overrides for most formatting related methods that take culture as one of arguments:

```
(3.3).ToString(new CultureInfo("fr-FR"))
```

Comment: so how do i set it for the form window that i am working on. it is not recognizing the thread

Comment: i am not really interested in defining for each transition. isn't that possible to set it for the form thread. you know when you create a new window form project ?

Comment: ok i found how to make :             System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US", false);
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US", false);

Answer (score 59):

With 4.0, you will need to manage this yourself by setting the culture for each thread as Alexei describes. But with 4.5, you can define a culture for the appdomain and that is the preferred way to handle this. The relevant apis are [CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) and [CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentuiculture.aspx).

Comment: Thanks all, but the 4.0 CurrentThread... version does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a Language Resource file to set the labels in your application you need to set the its value:

```
CultureInfo customCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Languages.Culture = customCulture;
```