# Default Culture

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, internationalization, cultureinfo, culture

I use .NET4

**I use en-US locale, and want my application to work that way only.**

Some of my software clients, though, are from countries (Norway - for example) where the decimal point is represented by ','.

Therefore the next line throws exception for my Norwegian client:

```
double a = double.Parse("1.5");
```

I've read I can change the CurrentCulture as follows:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

The problem is that I have to do this for each thread seperately. Moreover, I'm not totally sure where I will implicitly parse a double, so I will have to do it on each Thread creation...

I've read that there is a solution for .NET 4.5, by changing setting the `DefaultThreadCurrentCulture`.

Does anyone think of a general solution for this without upgrading my .NET framework version?

Comment: You can write your own parsing methods and specify conversion culture in  those.

Comment: Where would you have implicit conversion, with a c# application?

Comment: @mcy, I meant a more general solution, in which I don't have to find out all the places I parse double in my code...

Comment: @user1028741, what I meant is that sometimes in the code I call to a metadata code which does the double.parse(). That means that just looking for double.parse() in my code will not suffice...

Comment: Where do you get that number? User enters it? If so you should add mask/validation to prevent that.

Comment: One thing to note about avoiding the upgrade is that Microsoft is ending support for .NET 4.0 Jan-2016, so not upgrading has a limited lifetime  http://support2.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=pn&alpha=.net+framework

Comment: Could you update the metadata function you call to include the culture as well as finding the places in the code where you call parse directly?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354211/how-to-set-default-culture-info-for-entire-c-sharp-application?rq=1

Comment: The question is why your client has that string `"1.5"` at all. You should store those values as `double` and if the client gives you it as input you can't change that anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I know you're looking for a general solution, but the way I work around these issues is to parse using CultureInfo.InvariantCulture:

```
double a = double.Parse("1.5", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Beware though, this my cause issues when your string contains both commas and periods.

Check the answers at the following link:

[How do I parse a string with a decimal point to a double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354924/how-do-i-parse-a-string-with-a-decimal-point-to-a-double)

Comment: Not really "workaround", but rather "correct approach". Specifying culture explicitly is indeed the right solution when you know what culture is used. And `InvariantCulture` seem to be the one OP should be using as data likely comes from some other place than user input.

Answer (score -3):

i think i understood your problem and this could be done without upgrading your .Net i hope this helps 
as i was making a program i made a inital setup for my program in which i ask 
so make a Dialog that will ask the user for a country and then you add your decimal code as a case statement.here :-

`void AskForACountry()
        {
            frmEdit = new Form();
            frmEdit.ShowIcon = false;
            cmbxLang = new ComboBox();
            frmEdit.Size = new Size(199, 113);
            Button btnSetLang = new Button();
            btnSetLang.Size = new Size(88, 23);
            btnSetLang.Text = "Set Language";
            btnSetLang.Location = new Point(40, 39);
            cmbxLang.Location = new Point(28, 12);
            cmbxLang.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            String[] arrayCountry = { "Catalan - Spain", "Chinese - China", "Chinese - Hong Kong", "Chinese - Taiwan", "Danish - Denmark", "Dutch - Netherlands", "English - Australia", "English - Canada", "English - Great Britain", "English - US", "Finnish - Finland", "French - Canada", "French - France", "German - Germany", "Italian - Italy", "Japanese - Japan", "Korean - Korea", "Norwegian - Norway", "Polish - Poland", "Portuguese - Brazil", "Portuguese - Portugal", "Russian - Russia", "Spanish - Mexico", "Spanish - Spain", "Swedish - Sweden" };
            cmbxLang.DataSource = arrayCountry.ToList();
            btnSetLang.Click += new EventHandler(btnSetLang_Click);
            frmEdit.Controls.Add(cmbxLang);
            frmEdit.Controls.Add(btnSetLang);
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a country that fits your computer's default language and dialect.", "Select A Country");
            frmEdit.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            frmEdit.AcceptButton = btnSetLang;
            frmEdit.ShowDialog();
        }`

Comment: took it from my old program. Hope this helps :p or maybe i failed to understand the question