# How to fix a different decimal setting on a second computer C#

Tags: c#, settings

So as I've stated in my question I recently wrote a small program to calculate the amount of bricks needed to build a room, using the following

```
 float result = ((fLenght * fWitdh) * fHeight) * bricksPerMeter;
```

When Running a test case on both my main computer and a second computer they come up with a different answer

Ex: PC 1 ((15 * 1)* 1.8)* 40 = 1080

PC 2 with the same values produces 600 as the answer

now the error is fixed by changing the decimal symbol on the second computer

I want to know if there is anyway for my code to check if this is the case and attempt to fix it
without me going to each computer and setting it manually

Comment: _"now the error is fixed by changing the decimal symbol on the second computer"_ - huh? I feel like we must be missing some information here.

Comment: Okay the decimal symbol on the main computer is a point and on the second one its a comma by changing the symbol to be matching on both machines it worked if you want. i can link the github page it like 60 lines of code total

Comment: No, I understood that. I can only see this being an issue if you're taking user input in., but we don't see any evidence of that in your question, or any code for interpreting user input as a numeric value.

Comment: Bottom line is: once you have a `float` or a `double` in .NET, it doesn't matter what the current culture's decimal separator is because it has nothing to do with these types. It only matters when you interpret a string as a number, or format a number as a string.

Comment: Yes the user has to input the values sorry I didn't include that in the question they input the height length and width and select a radial button for the type of brick

Comment: OK, so how do you interpret (parse) the numbers? And why do you want to enforce a different way of parsing the numbers? Generalisation: on a German computer the decimal separator is a comma, and a German would feel perfectly at home inputting a decimal value in this way. On an British English computer, the decimal separator is a period, and a British English user would feel perfectly at home inputting a decimal in that way.

Comment: I'm using float.TryParse(value, out fValue) ? fValue : 1f

Comment: I'm trying to find a good duplicate, but you can force `.` by passing `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to `TryParse`.

Comment: Seems like you should be using `float.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out fValue);`

Comment: Thanks I'll try that I think that might have been my problem

Comment: Are you sure you want to make that change? If the default culture is, for example, German (Germany), then the default culture within your application will be German (Germany). This seems the correct way to go for a German user. It seems like the existing behaviour is the most correct.

Comment: I just had a look at the local on both systems one was on English and the other Japanese

Comment: If it's the Japanese one then that's rather odd. I wonder if someone had configured the system like that for a reason.

Comment: I think it's a mistake both are home computers i just wanted to make life a bit easier by removing one of the calculations that has to be done nearly daily  and ran into this issue didn't even know that different locals can cause problems

Comment: If it's serialised data that you're dealing with, you should normally use the InvariantCulture when serialising and deserialising - but if it's a string that's come from the user via the UI you normally use CurrentCulture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally when you launch a .NET application, it takes its default culture settings from the operating system. That is to say that computer configured for German (Germany) would result in the `de-de` culture being used in the application, and a computer configured for English (United Kingdom) would result in the `en-gb` culture being used in the application.

With these cultures come things like date format strings, decimal separators, etc. which is where your issue comes from.

A simple solution is to change your code, which is currently:

```
float.TryParse(value, out fValue) ? fValue : 1f
```

to use the [Invariant Culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=net-5.0#remarks):

```
float.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out fValue) ? fValue : 1f;
```

This will then use the invariant culture, whose decimal separator is `.`, to parse the string to a float.

Note that you'll probably want to enforce a culture when you convert the result back to a string. One way to do this is by passing a culture to the `.ToString` method:

```
string resultText = result.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(resultText);
```

Alternative solution (but not recommended): you could [override the default culture for your entire application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13354246/3181933) but that might cause problems for you elsewhere, so I don't recommend this.