How to guard against DateTime code breaking on Azure
I recently ran into an issue with the following line of code Linq:
var directions = unitDirections.Directions
.Where(d => Convert.ToDateTime(d.DueDate) > DateTime.Today || (Convert.ToDateTime(d.DueDate) <= DateTime.Today && d.DirStatus == "OPN")).ToList();

It all worked fine running local. But once published to Azure the code broke and had to be fixed with DateParse and Invariant Culture. This is due to the target OS being Linux. This is the code that fixed it:
unitDirections.Directions.Where(d => Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.ParseExact(d.DueDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) > DateTime.Today ||           (Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.ParseExact(d.DueDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) <= DateTime.Today && d.DirStatus == "OPN")).ToList();

Here's a related post: DateTime Parse Exact. Not working on Azure
How do I avoid this and guard against it in the future? Beyond trying to remember, is there a way to remind me when I build the project in Visual Studio? Is there any warning that could be set?

Maybe you should try explicitly setting the culture.  This might help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354211/how-to-set-default-culture-info-for-entire-c-sharp-application

What you linked to is unrelated, and if convert.ToDateTime is actually Convert.ToDateTime, the code never worked. You're calling Convert.ToDateTime(bool), which [according to the docs](Calling this method always throws InvalidCastException.) always throws InvalidCastException. Dates are binary values, they have no format. If dueDate is a real date, there's no need to parse it or convert it to anything. If it's a string, you have a critical bug. Change it to a proper Date type like DateTime or DateOnly instead of trying to guess string contents

The real solution is always to use proper date types. If there's no way to do that, eg in SQLite which has no data types, use the ISO8601 format only, ie YYYY-MM-DD .... Anything else is ambiguous and subject to interpretation. In XML and JSON the ISO8601 is the standard way to represent dates

Sorry for the lack of clarity. I updated the code sections to demonstrate. The question is. How do I avoid making this mistake again? I can try setting the culture to "invariant" for the thread.

@PanagiotisKanavos I've added in the exact code. Sorry for the confusion.

Invariant won't help, that's the US-only format. The standard is ISO8601 BUT you wouldn't have to parse anything if DueDate was an actual date. Where does DueDate come from and why is it a string? That's the real problem that needs to be fixed. In a database, change the type to at least date. In a JSON file - it should be ISO8601 already, which means you have data issues. When loading from CSV or other text files you need to know what format is used and parse at the time of import. CsvHelper for example requires a culture in advance and then maps both dates and numbers correctly

Thanks. I need to do some reading. Those dates are strings because the data comes from some HTML. I'll have to convert somewhere.

So you're using screen scraping? Are you trying to read an input type='date' element? The display text is localized to the browser's locale but the value itself is ISO8601. If you use Selenium or Playwright you can retrieve the value instead of the text. If you retrieve the HTML text itself, you can change the request language with the Accept-Language header

@PanagiotisKanavos, yes, it's a scraping task. I think the string is just inside a table cell. Not an input. But I'll check. Thanks for your help.

The html consists of input type=hidden for all the fields. They are made visible by js I think. It's a very old web app we have to scrape. It's awful.
