# BootStrap Datepicker return null from View to Controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, date, datepicker

1st i explain my problem,we are using BootStrap DatePicker, after submit the Html.BeginForm it goes to controller with select date and updating the database in my development system(pc) but the same coding is not working in testing server and client system. After debug on Testing server i found the datepicker return NULL to controller 
when i choose the Date more than 12 Day e.g (13-10-2014) and for less then 12 date like (12-10-2014) is working fine.

I [changed the culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729922/how-to-set-cultureinfo-invariantculture-default) as Invariant but still its return null value to controller

The datepicker defined inside the BeginForm, Other controls are returning the correct values expect the DatePicker.

```
Html.BeginForm("MergeTeacherDetails","Profile", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FormTeacherDetails" })))
```

The DatePicker Format changed as ('dd/mm/yyyy')
Here the View Code

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.DOB, "DOB", new { @class = "control-label"})
<div class="controls">
 @{System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DOB, new { placeholder = "DOB",@readonly = "readonly",@class="ReadOnly" })}
</div>
```

Here the JavaScript

```
$('#DOB').datepicker({ startView: 2, autoclose: true, format: "dd/mm/yyyy", endDate: '@DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")', changeYear: true, changeMonth: true, weekStart: 1 });
```

Here the DAL code

```
 public Nullable<System.DateTime> DOB { get; set; }
```

Here the Controller Code

```
public ActionResult MergeTeacherDetails(Staffs objStaffs)
    {

         int res = _staffRepository.InsertOrUpdate(objStaffs);
         if(res>0)
         {
          _mapStaffRepository.SaveMapStaff(objStaffs.StaffId);
         }
         return RedirectToAction("/MyProfile/1");
    }
```

In controller Parameter objStaffs.DOB is returns as NULL

This

Kindly help me to solve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: The Problem in this coding there is no ViewModel. If i want to create the ViewModel, its very complex to handle that in all over the project

Comment: Can you post controller code?

Comment: Can you help me to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure the application uses the expected date format when binding the posted values into datetime values using the model binder (when binding the posted values into your `objStafss` model)

By default the model binder will use the current culture format, which on your machine will probably be `dd/mm/yyyy` while on the testing/client machines will be `mm/dd/yyyy`.

You can create your model binder that always expects dates in the format `dd/mm/yyyy` (which in .net is expressed as dd/MM/yyyy):

```
public class CustomModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object GetPropertyValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext,
        PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, IModelBinder propertyBinder)
    {
        var propertyType = propertyDescriptor.PropertyType;         
        if(propertyType == typeof(DateTime) || propertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
        {
            var providerValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
            if (null != providerValue)
            {
                DateTime date;
                if (DateTime.TryParseExact(providerValue.AttemptedValue, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
                {
                    return date; 
                }                    
            }
        }
        return base.GetPropertyValue(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, propertyBinder);
    }
}
```

Then you need to tell MVC to use you model binder, for example you can wire it globally for your application in the global.asax `Application_Start` event by replacing the default binder:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new CustomModelBinder();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this code is working fine but when i choose the date (30/10/2014) it convert that date into (30-Jan-2014). Have you checked this scenario in your local

Comment: You will also need to make sure the format used when rendering an existing value to the textbox is `dd/mm/yyyy`. You could use the DisplayFormatAttribute as in `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]` but that only works with `EditorFor` and not `TextBoxFor`. You could either create a custom helper like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22071121/1836935) or your own editor template for datetimes

Comment: If you are using MVC 5.1+, you can add the DisplayFormat attribute and change your code to use EditorFor while still setting the html attributes like placeholder or readonly with `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dob, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "DOB", @readonly = "readonly", @class = "ReadOnly" } })`